# Pagedown Markdown Converter not working properly

Tags: javascript, editor, markdown

I am trying to convert markdown text to HTML using `pagedown` - Markdown Converter. It is not formatting properly.

Here is JsFiddle URL, where it seems to work for some tag - https://jsfiddle.net/oeraroks/

Here is the stack overflow snippet -

```js
var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
jQuery('.mdl-card__markdown-content').each(function() {
  text = jQuery(this).text();
  vhtml = converter.makeHtml(text);
  vhtml = vhtml.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
  jQuery(this).html(vhtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Sanitizer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Converter.min.js"></script>

<div class="mdl-card__markdown-content">
**DISCLAIMER** He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
* Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
* Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad. He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
</div>
```

If you can see in JSFiddle, you will see only `Disclaimer` text is getting bold. Rest all where list was expected remains untouched and no change.

**FAQ**

1. I am using SimpleMDE editor - https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor

Since, it has no option of changing it to HTML, I had to look down to `pagedown` converter for converting `markdown text` to `html text`.

Looking for help in converting above text to html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple of problems with your code.

I am not that good with markdown itself, but one thing I was noticing is that i needs a break between paragraph and a list to realize that list is there.

```
<div class="mdl-card__markdown-content">
**DISCLAIMER** He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. 
Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.

* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
* Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. Bryan Cranston 
played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
* Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad. He is also known 
for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
</div>
```

---

### See the difference even on this site (your version):

**DISCLAIMER** He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. 
    Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
* Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. Bryan Cranston 
played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
* He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
* Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad. He is also known 
    for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.

---

### ws (version with the break):

**DISCLAIMER** He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. 
    Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.

- He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
- Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
- He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle. Bryan Cranston 
  played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad.
- He is also known for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.
- Bryan Cranston played the role of Walter in Breaking Bad. He is also known 
  for playing Hal in Malcom in the Middle.

Then you might want to remove the

```
vhtml = vhtml.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

to make it look nicer

Comment: Damn that line created issue - I really need to inform user and do some extra code. Removed `vhtml.replace` too Thanks